# How to change highlighted warning/error text background color in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I'm using Retta color theme in eclipse. The problem is when I hover with the mouse over the warning or error symbols, it gives me a white background and I can't see a thing.

[Highlighted text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPHpY.png)

Where I can change that? I've already tried going to **General>Editors>Text Editors>Annotations**, but changing the options there didn't solve the problem (like making Text as Underline and so on). **The problem only occurs when I hover the mouse over the warning/error symbol**.

Comment: Please post your code as actual text content and not as image.

Comment: Why? The code have multiple includes to make it work here, besides, any warning or error have the same behavior no matter the code.

Answer (score 0):

First you should over the word with the highlighted background and then proceed to right click, then go to **Preferences > Appearance color options**

Then you should be able to adjust the colors to your liking.

Comment: I've changed everything to black in these options, but still gives me a light background (even disabled every highlight options I've found) =/